# Blind bearing bore design

Tags: machining, bearings

I've tried to find some rules of thumb about this without any luck. I'm designing a part with a blind cartridge bearing bore. It's a 624 bearing (13x4x5) and the fit size guides point me to a tolerance of 13.0-13.026mm for the bore for my application, so slip fit on the housing. FWIW the shaft is the rotating part of the design and will be pressed into the inner race. Do I need to create some kind of lip or shelf inside the bore so that the inner race doesn't come into contact with the housing and create friction? It seems like this would obviously be a concern if both the inner race and outer race are the same thickness.[image: housing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normally the solution, both to avoid the inner race touching or the shaft it supports.

Another method is to fit a spacer / washer to do the same thing - possibly cheaper but can be left out when taken apart.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider a way to get bearing out of the block as well. Consider putting 3 holes tangential to the bearing to tap the bearing out with a drift. Thin cylinders tend to get cockeyed and gall up the surface, then you would have difficulty inserting a new replacement bearing, more applicable for steel on steel, than steel bearing on a dissimilar metal(or plastic). In tool and die work, it is very common to have tight press fits between inserts and the die block, the insert might be a hard tool steel like D2, while the die might also be D2 or a cheaper steel like O2. In that situation I used to use a anti-galling anti-seize compound, typically copper powder in a oil binder, but molybdenum anti-seize compounds also exist.